# How do i display the current Time in Xamarin using xaml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin.forms

When i use **DateTime.Today** in DatePicker element it's running and gives me proper output but when i use **DateTime.Now** in TimePicker element it returns me error

1. **Error**
   Position 17:21. Cannot assign property "Time": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<DatePicker Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" />
<TimePicker Time="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `Time` Property on the `TimePicker` is of type `TimeSpan`, while `DateTime.Now` is of type `DateTime`. You'll need to use the `TimeOfDay` property on a `DateTime` object.

**Edit:** Turns out, you can't bind to `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` directly, so you'll need to do it one of two other ways:

1) Either define a Property on the target of the `BindingContext` of the page using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) tutorial

or 2) Give the `TimePicker` a name and set the `Time` property on it in the code behind

Comment: Thank you for the response,  but it's complaining on Now.TimeOfDay. error is Type expected and static member expected

Comment: thank you again for your quick response, i just want to ask you one more thing about the first technique you told me in your answer, my question is that Time property of TimePicker element has already the Backing field in TImePicker class with the name TimeProperty, then how can i remake the Time property as backing field.